# Combining Susy at-breakpoint() and device orientation media queries

Tags: susy-compass

I'm relatively new to Susy and responsive design. I've managed to setup my grid and using at-breakpoint(), I've made the page fully responsive as required first by testing it while resizing the browser window, and then testing it on the actual mobile devices (phones and tablets). I encounter a problem with the iPad as requires an extra orientation rule (orientation: landscape) in the media query. What's the workaround here, is there a way to include it in the at-breakpoint rule or I'll have to make up a separate media query just for this case?

Here's my grid setup:

```
$total-columns: 4;
$column-width: 60px;
$gutter-width: 20px;
$grid-padding: $gutter-width/2;

// alternative layout breakpoints

$tablet-small: 6;
$tablet: 8;
$computer: 12;
```

And when dealing with the sidebar and the page body, first I display them as block elements to fill the entire page horizontally, and after the breakpoint I make them behalf as columns like so:

```
#sidebar {
    @include at-breakpoint($computer) {
        @include span-columns(3, $computer);
    }
} // sidebar

#page-body {
    @include at-breakpoint($computer) {
        @include span-columns(9 omega, $computer);
    }
} // page-body
```

How should I alter the code so that it keeps the variables for the breakpoints and just add the orientation rule? Thanks!

Comment: Whats the value of the $container-style: variable (in _base.scss?)? fluid? or magic?

Comment: Are you trying to force landscape orientation on the ipad? The way susy works is basically all about screen or window width, thus allowing the user to orient the device whichever way they want. Or are you just wanting the ipad to view the full width block style in landscape orientation and the column mode when in portrait orientation?

Comment: Sass allows you to nest media-queries (creating one query with "and"). So you can simply nest orientation inside at-breakpoint, or vice versa. That said, I think you may be better off with something like this: https://github.com/scottjehl/iOS-Orientationchange-Fix to solve the orientation-change bug. Then you can keep your layout controls more broadly based on width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to target specific device, I think it's better to specify the width.

So instead of `$computer: 12;` maybe do `$computer: 48em 12;`

Once the `min-width: 48em;` is reached, it will change the layout to become a 12 column grid.

Comment: Sorry but I'm a bit lost. If I add a width to the breakpoints, I get this error: (Line 21 of _functions.scss: (48em 12) is not a number for `round')

Comment: I'm not sure what's on your line 21, but if you do `$computer: 48em 12`, you can't do `@include span-columns(9 omega, $computer);`. Change it to `@include span-columns(9 omega, 12);`. That might be the cause of your error message.

Answer (score 0):

something like this SHOULD work:

```
$device-lrg-landscape: max-device-width 480px, orientation landscape


@include breakpoint($device-lrg-landscape)
```